# How to get coordinates around specific coordinate (x, y) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

As in title I am struggling with getting coordinates that are around specific coordinate. In this example I will say 24, 7.

[image]

Comment: Well, what don't you like about it? I don't see anything hard coded except for "1" and that pretty much needs to be hard coded. Before people start working on this, we need to know what you're going to reject because you don't like it...

Comment: I guess it could be coded better, lets say loops?

Comment: Please explain what the importance is of grid and map? Which of the two would limit the output of boundary coordinates?

Comment: I mean't that map is 128x128 and each "field" is 32x32 pixels. I explained it wrong i assume.

Comment: Well i'll leave it like that then, thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not really the place for "can you do this better", unless there is a specific, objective measure of "better". If you want a review of all of your code, and it's something you wrote, [read this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and if the question seems to pass muster (you may want to ask on [meta.codereview.se]) you can try posting on [codereview.se].

Comment: I don't get *map is 128x128 and each "field" is 32x32 pixels*. Are the coordinates for the field or for the map? What is the maximum possible value for `x` and `y`? The minumum?

Comment: @slider min 0, 0 max 128, 128

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you want to not only achieve this, but achieve it *nicely!* In my personal opinion, this could be made "nice" by working with a definition of "adjacency" explicit in the code.

```js
// This code makes "adjacency" explicit by working with "adjacency offset generators"
// These are functions which return all offsets that move a point to all of its adjacent points

let manhattanAdjacencyOffsets = dist => {
  // Returns adjacency offsets corresponding to all points within a manhattan distance of `dist`
  let ret = [];
  for (let x = -dist; x <= dist; x++) { for (let y = -dist; y <= dist; y++) {
    if (x === 0 && y === 0) continue; // Don't include the 0,0 point
    ret.push({ x, y });
  }}
  return ret;
};

// Now `nCoordinates` becomes very short:
let nCoordinates = (x0, y0, adjacencyOffsets) => {
  return adjacencyOffsets.map(({ x, y }) => ({ x: x + x0, y: y + y0 }));
};

// Here's manhattan adjacency offsets with a distance of 1
let adjacencyOffsets = manhattanAdjacencyOffsets(1);

// And here's all neighbours of the point (10,20), with regard to those offsets
let neighbours = nCoordinates(10, 20, adjacencyOffsets);
console.log(neighbours);
```

I like this approach because it makes "adjacency" explicit. You could even define new adjacency functions to change your code's definition of "adjacency".

For example you could use cartesian distance instead of manhattan distance (all points within a circular range of the source tile):

```
let cartesianAdjacencyOffsets = dist => {
  let sqrDist = dist * dist;
  let ret = [];
  let min = Math.ceil(-dist);
  let max = Math.floor(dist);
  for (let x = min; x <= max; x++) { for (let y = min; y <= max; y++) {
    if (x === 0 && y === 0) continue; // Don't include the 0,0 point
    if (sqrDist < x * x + y * y) continue; // Don't include points too far away
    ret.push({ x, y });
  }}
  return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use two loops in this case:

```
 const results = [];

  for(const dx of [-1, 0, 1]) {
   for(const dy of [-1, 0, 1]) {
     if(dx === 0 && dy === 0) continue;
     results.push({ x: x + dx, y: y + dy });
  }
}
```

Or just:

```
 const neighbours = [
    [-1, -1], [-1,  0], [-1,  1],
    [ 0, -1], /*0, 0*/  [ 0,  1], 
    [ 1, -1], [ 1,  0], [ 1,  1]
 ];

 const results = neighbours.map(([dx, dy]) => ({ x: x + dx, y: y + dy }));
```

Comment: for(n of x) carries a processing penalty over for(n=0; n<x.length; n++) if I recall, and might run slower than the OP code... but this is certainly more terse.

Comment: You're not considering edge cases where coordinates may go beyond the board.

Comment: @slider that isn't quite clear from the question though, therefore I can't consider it.

Comment: @JECarter so what? Did you notice those 10000 nanoseconds that it took you to read this text? The difference between `for..of` and `for` is probably 1 nanosecond ... why do you care?

Comment: Sorry, Jonas, didn't mean to criticize, just help provide a better answer.  Sometimes people care about performance when the scope goes beyond an example.  Take it for what it's worth.

Comment: @JECarter nothing to apologize for, criticism isn't a bad thing (at least if it is meant to imrpove things like in this case). However I still disagree, if people care about performance they would write that code in assembly (or they just trust V8 to do its best, which it'll do in both cases). "premature optimizations are the root of all evil"

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways, both O(n).

1. The first one is so simple, efficient and ugly that i think it's a sin in CS to do such things.

```js
var neighborFunctions = [ (x,y) => [x+1,y]
                        , (x,y) => [x+1,y+1]
                        , (x,y) => [x,y+1]
                        , (x,y) => [x-1,y+1]
                        , (x,y) => [x-1,y]
                        , (x,y) => [x-1,y-1]
                        , (x,y) => [x,y-1]
                        , (x,y) => [x+1,y-1]
                        ],
    getNeigborCoords  = (x,y) => Array.from({length:8}, (_,i) => neighborFunctions[i](x,y)),
    result            = getNeigborCoords(24,7);


console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

2. Now lets dive into another sin but a functional one, `Math.sin()`.

```js
var getNeigborCoords = (x,y) => Array.from( {length:8}
                                          , (_,i) => [ x+Math.round(Math.cos(Math.PI*i/4))
                                                     , y+Math.round(Math.sin(Math.PI*i/4))
                                                     ]
                                          ),
    result           = getNeigborCoords(24,7);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Since the second one is a functional solution you may develop it further to calculate the second neighbors and whatnot.